# I've the menu twice in 13.10/unity after trying gnome flashback and installing nvidia-prime

Tags: unity, gnome, nvidia, themes

I tried gnome flashback and installed nvidia-prime just after, so maybe one of these is responsible.

I've got a messed up interface under unity with menus in the system bar AND in the app itself. How do I keep menu only in the system bar? And with the right theme? I went to Setting to put the default theme back with no luck.

Below is a screenshot of the problem
[image]

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug with nvidia prime actually, i suppresed it and it's ok now